# should I delete static object in c++

Tags: c++

before my main function I declare a static pointer array with new pointers to an object that implement the base array class, and I want to know if I should delete it (or only the classes) myself with "delete".

```
static AStudentList* a = new AStudentList();
static BStudentList* b = new BStudentList();
static CStudentList* c = new CStudentList();
static DStudentList* d = new DStudentList();
static InstitutionStudentList* instArr[4] = {a, b, c, d};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
}
```

Comment: Why use heap allocation for static?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to `delete` each of the four objects before your program ends, like so:

```
delete instArr[0];
delete instArr[1];
delete instArr[2];
delete instArr[3];
```

You should not `delete` the array, because it was not dynamically allocated.

However, I can see no reason to use dynamically allocated objects here. Why not just do:

```
static AStudentList a;
static BStudentList b;
static CStudentList c;
static DStudentList d;
static InstitutionStudentList* instArr[4] = {&a, &b, &c, &d};
```

Then you have nothing to `delete`.

Comment: good point on not using dynamically allocated objects at all.

Comment: +1 for the part about avoiding dynamic allocation.  However, explicitly deleting them before the program ends is potentially dangerous; what if there's a local variable that relies on their existence?  A better approach (for dynamic allocation) would be to use a smart pointer to manage their lifetime automatically.

Answer (score 3):

A simple rule of thumb is that each for each `new` call you should have exactly one `delete` call. So in this case you need to delete 4 times - the 4 pointers stored in the array `instArr` but you should not delete the array itself.

Answer (score 2):

Automate your clean-up:

```
static AStudentList a;
static BStudentList b;
static CStudentList c;
static DStudentList d;
static InstituationStudentList* instArray[] = { &a, &b, &c, &d };
```

Unless there is a really strong reason to allocate objects on the heap don't do it. If you really absolutely have to us heap allocated objects, use

```
static std::unique_ptr<AStudentList> a(new AStudentList);
...
static InstituationStudentList* instArray[] = { a.get(), ... };
```

You should also try hard to **avoid** any global object! They start their life being a legacy and that just grows quickly.

Answer (score 1):

Yes because it has been allocated on heap using the `operator new`. Just because you declare a variable as static, it does not mean the variable was created on stack and the memory will be freed automatically.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you should. You should always release any memory you allocate.

That being said, you will probably release it, just before you call `exit()` or otherwise end your program. The operating system's kernel will then automatically release the memory. The end result then is basically the same.

Consider the future when you create code. Perhaps your code will be some kind of plugin in the future and if you then fail to release also the `static` memory, you will have introduced a memory leak. Also if you later decide to remove the `static` keyword.

Comment: In very complex programs, it can be a performance optimization to not delete all memory allocations just before closing the program. But it is very rare that you would notice the difference in performance

Answer (score 0):

Once you're done with resources you create, they should be deleted. If you simply terminate the program then it's not necessary as the system will do it for you, but as a matter of being proper, any resource you've created should be destroyed by you prior to termination. In addition to being proper, this makes things easier for you should you find it necessary to use tools such as Valgrind that track this for you to help find leaks.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need to delete them because their lifetime is the whole program and you never need to replace them with new objects then there is no purpose in storing them into the heap.

Otherwise you should delete them.

You can always use a pointer even if you store them directly in data segment:

```
static AStudentList a;
static const AStudentList* aPtr() { return &a; }
```